# How to do complete Appium Setup in Mac OS High Sierra (Version : 10.13.4)

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android, appium-desktop

Please help me in configuring appium from the terminal. Please provide the complete steps to do it along with the software versions.

Comment: go through this link :https://github.com/saikrishna321/VodQa_MobileAutomationWorkShop/wiki/Appium-Mac-Installation

Comment: How to uninstall something that is installed through sudo command?

Comment: @SoubhagyaMishra which method did you use to install it? Normally tools that install things have uninstall commands as well. For npm it is: npm uninstall <name>

Answer (score 0):

This is a little guide I've created for setting up Appium on Mac, but I'm sure you can find a lot of tutorials on this just by googling it.

First, you will need to download **Android Studio**: https://developer.android.com/studio/

After that, set ANDROID_HOME path in your ".bash_profile" file:

Navigate to home directory (type "cd" anywhere in terminal to go to home directory), type "ls -a" to list all files, ".bash_profile" file should be listed (if it's not listed create it with "touch .bash_profile"), add following lines to ".bash_profile" file:

## Path to ANDROID_HOME

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users//Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

after saving file type "source .bash_profile" for changes to take effect.

**Homebrew**

HomeBrew is a command line package manager for OS X. It is not officially recognized, but it has become a standard de facto for the distributions of tons of useful tools. Install it by running following command from Terminal:

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)". For more info about Homebrew visit: https://brew.sh/

**Python 2.7**

Python should be pre-installed on macOS. To check if Python is installed type "python --version" in Terminal, output should show currently installed version (e.g. "Python 2.7.10"). If Python is not installed for some reason, you can install latest version with command "brew install python"

**Appium and Appium dependencies**

Install Appium desktop application from here http://appium.io/ (e.g. "appium-desktop-1.2.6-mac.zip")

Install carthage which is an Appium dependency with command "brew install carthage --HEAD" (if you want to see where carthage is installed type "which carthage")

Install pip package manager with command "sudo easy_install pip"

Install Appium Python client (if you want Java, Ruby, C# client, just change it, instead of Python) with command "pip install Appium-Python-Client"

Install Node.js and NPM with command "brew install node" (to verify node and npm are installed type "node -v" and "npm -v" in terminal)

Install appium doctor with command "sudo npm install appium-doctor -g". Appium doctor will tell you if there are some missing dependencies, to use it type "appium-doctor" in terminal.

Run commands "sudo npm install -g authorize-ios" and "sudo authorize-ios"

Set JAVA_HOME path in your ".bash_profile" file:

Navigate to home directory (type "cd" anywhere in terminal to go to home directory), type "ls -a" to list all files, ".bash_profile" file should be listed, edit ".bash_profile" with the next lines:

## Path to Java

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH

after saving file type "source .bash_profile" for changes to take effect

If everything is set up correctly, when you run `appium-doctor` from Terminal you will see something like this:

```
username$ appium-doctor
info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.4.3
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: 
/usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 8.9.0
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Carthage was found at: /usr/local/bin/carthage
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/majdukovic
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: 
/Users/majdukovic/Library/Android/sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: 
/Users/majdukovic/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: 
/Users/majdukovic/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: 
/Users/majdukovic/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Bin directory of $JAVA_HOME is set
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic completed, no fix needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor 
info AppiumDoctor Everything looks good, bye!
info AppiumDoctor 
username$
```

[image]